# Can't figure out how to pass a BYTE* to this method

Tags: c, byte

I'm trying to pass a variable to this function:

```
void PutMem (ADDRESS, BYTE*, int);
```

My code for it looks like this:

```
while (wcounter < len)
    {
        container[0] = line[index];
        container[1] = line[index + 1];
        container[2] = '\0';



        PutMem(adr, &container, 0);

        wcounter++;
        index += 2;
        adr++;
    }
```

The container variable is an unsigned char * 
but I have no clue how to get that to be a BYTE for the function to accept.

Comment: Hi. Please remember to provide a [mcve] for questions. You also did not provide any errors, which is normally required to understand a problem.

Comment: What is the third parameter of that function supposed to be? I would assume you should provide the pointer to the first element of a `BYTE` array and a length of that area. Then you should simply change it from `0` to `3`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not provided in your example but I will assume that the BYTE definition is standard, in which case, an *unsigned char* is the same thing as a "BYTE".

First, you should understand that the function requires a *pointer to a BYTE* and not a BYTE. Second, *container* appears to be an *array of unsigned char* and not an *unsigned char*. That means you need to pass it like this `&container[0]` to *PutMem* but that is also assuming you always want the first element.

This is the best answer I can provide without more detail.

Comment: All your assumptions are correct. 
I've make container an unsigned char, but I am trying to pass the function a 2 digit hex value as the byte, so I need all of container to be passed, not just the first value.

Comment: The function accepts a pointer, not an array. You cannot pass it a reference to the array. By passing a pointer the first element of the array, *PutMem* can access the other elements, depending on the implementation.